# MongoDB Bulk Find and Replace of ObjectId on a single Document

Tags: mongodb, replace, objectid, bulkupdate

We have two documents that have merged and they now have one one ObjectId.
There exists a configuration document that may have references to the old ObjectId. The old ObjectID can exist all over this document which is full of nested arrays and lists.
We want to do a simple find and replace on this document, preferably without replacing the entire document itself.

Is there a generic way to set every field that has ObjectIdA as a value and replace it with ObjectIdB?

Comment: Can you show us an example document that may have references to the old ObjectId ?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do that, no. You need to perform updates on all possible paths explicitly.